# Remove everything between two characters including the characters

Tags: python, regex

```
string = "$hahahaha$hahahaha hello";
```

How can I remove everything between the 2 $'s and also the $'s so I end up with:

```
hahahaha hello
```

The $ could also be '@' or '*' or '&' or '?'

Comment: I made a small update

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
([$@*&?]).*?\1(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pK9gX3/4)**

And grab the 2nd capturing group

[image]

Answer (score 6):

use a regular expression

```
import re

string = "$hahahaha$hahahaha hello"
stripped = re.sub("[$@*&?].*[$@*&?]", "", string)
print stripped
```

should output

```
hahahaha hello
```

Comment: There are some issues with this. For example, re.sub("[$@*&?].*[$@*&?]", "", "$aaaasf@hello") will also return "hello". And, re.sub("[$@*&?].*[$@*&?]", "", "$aaaa$he$ll$o") will return "o". Though the question is not specific, I think the former should not be stripped and the latter should return "heo". However, if there is no possibility of multiple pairs of tags (like my second example) or non-matching pairs of [$@*&?] (like my first), this should be fine.

Comment: yes it will. the regex only matches the first set of characters and whatever is between them so $hahahaha$hahahaha hello would return hahahaha hello.

Comment: the problem is that he didn't specify if it should remove multiple cases, or whether or not both $s could be any of the other special characters. If the use case was more clear, I would have provided a more specific regex

Answer (score 3):

If you are not comfortable using regular expression, you can use find() method. Please check the following code:

```
>>> string = "$hahahaha$hello"
>>> ch = '$'
>>> pos_1 = string.find(ch)
>>> if pos_1 < len(string) - 2:
...   pos_2 = string[pos_1+1:].find(ch) + pos_1 + 1
... 
>>> if pos_2 < len(string) - 1:
...   string = string[0:pos_1] + string[pos_2+1:]
... else:
...   string = string[0:pos_1]
... 
>>> string
'hello'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = "$hahahaha$hello";
ma = re.search(r'([$@*&?])(.+)\1(.+)$', string)
print ma.group(2), ma.group(3)
```

Comment: I modified this to include the additional delimiters. Also, this pattern will make sure delimiters are paired -- meaning if the first delimiter is a dollar sign, the second must also be a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = "$hahahaha$hahahaha hello"
print text.replace(re.findall(r'\$(.*?)\$', text)[0],'').replace('$','')
```

but needs to be expanded for other characters besides $ and for multiple strings between the $ character.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [42]: s = "$hahahaha$hahahaha hello"

In [43]: " ".join(s.rsplit("$",1)[1:])
Out[43]: 'hahahaha hello'

In [44]: (re.split("[$@*&?]",s)[-1])
 Out[44]: 'hahahaha hello'
```